# how to access overwritten method

Tags: javascript, inheritance, overriding, prototype, super

I have the following:

```
// Person constructor
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
}

// Greeting
Person.prototype.greeting = function(){
return `Hello there ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
}

const person1 = new Person('John', 'Doe');

// Customer constructor
function Customer(firstName, lastName, phone, membership) {
   Person.call(this, firstName, lastName);
   this.phone = phone;
   this.membership = membership;
}

const customer = new Customer('Tom', 'Smith', '555-555-5555', 'Standard');

// Inherit the Person prototype methods
Customer.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

// Make customer.prototype return Customer()
Customer.prototype.constructor = Customer;

// Create customer
const customer1 = new Customer('Tom', 'Smith', '555-555-5555', 'Standard');

// Customer greeting
Customer.prototype.greeting = function(){
return `Hello there ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName} welcome to our company`;
}
```

so for customer1 I can access the customer.greeting() with console.log(customer1.greeting()).  How do I access the Person.greeting() for customer1?

UPDATE:

the answer provided by Felix Kling is interesting but it doesn't seem to answer the question.  He seems to be showing how to overwrite the overwritten method.  My question is it possible to access both greeting methods and if so how?

If we used class the following I think should work:

```
class Customer extends Person {
    greeting(); //should return Customer.greeting()
    super.greeting(); //should return Person.greeting()  
}
```

Is this correct and is it possible to do the same without using classes?

SECOND UPDATE

in es5 we can do:

```
console.log(customer1.constructor.prototype.greeting.call(customer1))
```

or

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(customer1.constructor.prototype).greeting.call(customer1));
```

to get the parent method of greeting. and we can use:

```
customer1.greeting()
```

to get the customer greeting method.

in es6 we can use classes and do the following:

```
class Person {
    constructor(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    greeting() {
       return `Hello there ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}

class Customer extends Person {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, phone, membership) {
       super(firstName, lastName);
       this.phone = phone;
       this.membership = membership;
     }

     greeting(){
         console.log(super.greeting()) 
         return `Hello there ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName} ${this.phone}`
    }

}

const john = new Customer('John', 'Doe', '555-555-5555', 'Standard');
console.log(john.greeting());
```

so within the class we can access the Person.greeting using super but the following does not work

```
console.log(john.super.greeting());
```

so, given john, who is a customer and customers are persons is there a way to access super outside of the class?

Comment: Why arent you just using js Classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Person.prototype` is the prototype of `Customer.prototype`. So you can call `Person.prototype.gretting` like so:

```
Customer.prototype.greeting = function() {
  Object.getPrototypeOf(this.constructor.prototype).greeting.call(this);
}
```

Classes make this much easier btw:

```
class Customer extends Person {
  greeting() {
    super.greeting();
  }
}
```

Comment: your first answer isn't really helpful as you just change the overwritten method. Is it possible to have both the customer greeting and also the person greeting at the same time? In the second example you seem to be overwriting the greeting function back to Person.  That's not what I'm asking.  How do you access both greeting functions?

Comment: Ah I guess I misunderstood what you were asking then. If I understand you correctly now, there is no "simple" way to do this due to how prototype inheritance works. A property higher up in the prototype chain will always shadow a property with the same name that is lower in the prototype chain. Your only options are: (1) Expose the "lower" property via a different name, e.g. you could simply rename `Customer.prototype.greeting` to `Customer.prototype.superGreeting` or whatever. ...

Comment: (2) The caller needs to reach into the prototype chain just as I've shown above, e.g. `Object.getPrototypeOf(customer1.constructor.prototype).greeting.call(customer1);`, but then the caller has to make assumptions about the structure of the object, which is bad.

Comment: I've updated my question - you should see SECOND UPDATE.  Could you review and comment of whether or not we can access super outside the class?

Comment: You can do exactly the same that you do without classes. Classes are just syntactic sugar (more or less). You are still dealing with constructor functions and prototypes at runtime. There is no ES6 specific way to access the method of a parent class. And there shouldn't be because what you are attempting to already breaks encapsulation. The caller shouldn't have to know about the implementation details of your classes (there are always exceptions of course).